# redirect after form submit button

Tags: html

When i submit form i have

```
<form action="/search/" >
    <input type="text" name='q' / value="">
    <input type="submit"  value="Search" />
</form>
```

http://domain/search/?q=submit_text_here

I want after click submit button have url 
 http://domain/search/submit_text_here

How this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to handle form submission manually. For this you would bind to `onsubmit` form event, prevent its default behavior and make redirect to proper URL. Something like this in your case:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = '/search/' + encodeURIComponent(this.elements.q.value);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `RewriteRule`. This is a rule specified in the `.htaccess` file of your web directory that dictates special things the server should do. Using this, we can take your query string, map it to a user friendly url, and pare it using the standard index.php file, or any of your choosing.

**.htaccess**

```
# Match a condition:
# http://example.com/search/?query=find+something
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} query=([^&]+)

# Redirect that condition to
# http://example.com/search/find+something
RewriteRule  ^search/$  search/%1  [L,R=301,NC]

# Match the previous rule, and serve results from our search page
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
```

All the other responses will do what you asked, and change the URL, however none of them will map that newly formatted URL to a single page that will serve up results.

Comment: This is correct, but OP needs that `after click submit button have url http://domain/search/submit_text_here`. Mode rewrite will not make browser send GET request to such URL, it will just handle them properly if they come in this form.

Comment: Using a form action of `http://example.com/search/` with a method of `get` would result in this rewrite working correctly. -> `http://example.com/search/?query=find+something` <- matches first condition.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm saying that mode rewrite will not make browser submit form to `http://example.com/search/find+submiting` in the first place. Mode rewrite will handle it properly if such request comes, but to send request in this form is the client side job.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Fair enough.

Comment: But if OP doesn't have rewriting set up already (maybe framework already has some htaccess), then your answer is the second phase of this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible via PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    header ('Location: http://domain/search/' . $_GET['q']);
    exit;
}
```

Of course, you need to have in your `.htaccess` rewrite to this URL to avoid `404 Not Found` error.